# Forced Logout action after end of session remember me time

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2, logout

I am logging in the user using zf2 authenticate method. After the user is validate I store the user in a session which expires after 2 minutes. I want it so that the user is automatically logged out with or without a warning coming upon the screen once the session has timed out. Below is the code for the session storage.

```
      if ($result->isValid()) {

                $redirect = 'edit';


                    $this->getSessionStorage()
                         ->setRememberMe(); // sets the session to 2 minutes
                    //set storage again
                    $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($this->getSessionStorage());

                $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->write($request->getPost('EMAIL'));
            }
```

Comment: There's nothing to do. When the session expires, `isAuth()` will return false, which means that the user will not be logged anymore.

Comment: Is it not possible to redirect to login page after expiration ?

Comment: Everything is possible :). Depends on how you want it to work. A solution would be to check if the user is authenticated on each page. And if he is not, he is redirected to your login page. Though with this solution, it's not dynamic, you'd have to wait that the user loads a page.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant do this with php because you need to send the request to server for checking of session is expired. You may have to use js for it. Sending a request to server using ajax to check if session is expired and the reload the page accordingly